# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list. How to fix?

Tags: python, list, typeerror, indices

There's the code with the TypeError in it. "list indices must be integers, not list", though they are integers. I'd appreciate you helping me figure out what's wrong.  What I need is to get matrix 7x5 from source 7x5 tab with different values. The error occurs on the last line.

```
lines = []

with open("text.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = [int(x) for x in line if (x != ' ') and (x != '\n')]
        lines.append(line)
    f.close()
```

What I have after reading file is list of lists with numbers called "lines". It's integers. Not strings. Like:

```
>> [[1, 2, 3...], [4, 5, 6...], [7, 8, 9...],[...]]


i = 1
j = 1
T = []
T.append(lines[0][0])
```

I made this for avoiding `IndexError` (list out of range) on last line (`i-1` and stuff). Though, I don't think it's python-way really. I'd appreciate help with this thing too.

```
for i in lines:
    for j in lines:
        T[i][j] = lines[i][j] + max(T[i][j-1], T[i-1][j])
```

This is where error occurs. I don't get what should I fix if `i`, `j` are already `int`.

Comment: If the python runtime tells you it's not an integer then it's not an integer. Simply debug it with a few print statements to see for yourself...

Answer (score 5):

`i` and `j` are not indices; they are values from the `lines` list. Python `for` loops are [for-each constructs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop).

Use:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    for j, value in enumerate(line):
        T[i][j] = value + max(T[i][j - 1 % len(T[i])] + T[i - 1 % len(T)][j])
```

where the `% len()` calculations 'wrap around' to the last entry in `T` or `T[i]` when `i` and / or `j` are `0`. The [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) adds indices to the loop.

This does assume you already pre-built a nested list of lists structure in `T`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in lines:
    for j in lines:
```

`i` and `j` iterate over the elements of `lines`, not the indices. That means `i` and `j` are always lists, entire lines of numbers.

If you want to go over the indices (usually you don't, but it may be the best option here), you want

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    for j in range(len(lines[i])):
```

This is awkward by design, as the Python designers want people to default to iterating over the elements of a sequence.

Also, note that your loop tries to access elements of `lines` before the first row and before the first column. Perhaps you want to start your loops on the second row and column.