# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not set Python

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, set, reduce

What I am trying to do here is to take a list of sets as input and return a set of elements that occur in all of the given sets. I am getting a `'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not set'` error. I do not understand why this is the case since `range(len(list_of_sets))` is a list of integers.

```
def intersection_of_sets(list_of_sets):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: list_of_sets[x] &\
    list_of_sets[y], range(len(list_of_sets)))

print(intersection_of_sets([{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 2, 5}]))
```

This OUTPUT that I am going for is `set([2])`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431647/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-list-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs on the second iteration/step of the `reduce()` operation since the first iteration/step produced a set:

```
list_of_sets[0] & list_of_sets[1]  # returns a set
```

You can observe it if you debug it and print out the values of `x` and `y`:

```
def intersection_of_sets(list_of_sets):
    def merge_function(x, y):
        print(x, y)
        return list_of_sets[x] & list_of_sets[y]

    return reduce(merge_function, range(len(list_of_sets)))
```

You would see printed:

```
0 1
{2, 3} 2  # < we've got a problem here
...
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set
```

---

What you meant to do is to reduce the `list_of_sets` itself:

```
def intersection_of_sets(list_of_sets):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, list_of_sets)
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from functools import reduce

In [2]: def intersection_of_sets(list_of_sets):
   ...:     return reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, list_of_sets)
   ...: 

In [3]: print(intersection_of_sets([{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 2, 5}]))
set([2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are accessing a whole set, such as `{1,2,3}`.
Try instead:

```
set([2][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all of them works:

```
def intersection_of_sets(list_of_sets):
    res = list_of_sets[0]
    for s in list_of_sets[1:]:
        res &= s
    return res

print(intersection_of_sets([{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 2, 5}]))
```

Output:

```
{2}
```

Here `&=` is the in-place operator, meaning the same as `res = res & s`.

Answer (score 0):

Sets have a built in function, [intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {1, 2, 4}
c = {0, 2, 5}
a.intersection(b).intersection(c)
```

returns: `{2}`

Just create a recursive function to compare the first two and push the result until you only have a length of one on either the array or the result set.

```
def compareSets(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1: return arr[0]
    intersect = arr[0].intersection(arr[1])
    if len(arr) == 0: return {}
    arr.append(intersect)
    return compareSets(arr)
```